# Woocommerce Sorting function is not working with WOOF - WooCommerce Products Filter

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add sort by rating, price, and popularity option on the shop page of my wordpress website.

Also, want to add the filter by attribute.

I used *WOOF - WooCommerce Products Filter* for adding filter option. My sorting option is not working with this.

Comment: Please first read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In the WOOF - WooCommerce Products Filter settings, you can enable extensions. There is sorting by rating, sorting by price, featured products. Do you use these extensions? If not, then enable these extensions and click "Save".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried these extensions but it is showing filter by rating like rating from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 2 to 3, 3 to 4 or 4 to 5. I want all the option under on sort dropdown like in the following website. https://www.reebonz.com/sg/women/indemand/bags

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same snippet & it is working fine. You can use custom option of woocommerce & use as many sortings as you like.

```html
add_filter('woof_order_catalog', function($sort_args){

$sort_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
// Sort by meta_value because we're using alphabetic sorting
$sort_args['order'] = 'asc';
$sort_args['meta_key'] = 'meta-key';

return $sort_args;

});
```